# "will become accustomed to" or "will be accustomed to"?

Tags: verb-forms

Which of the following sentences is correct:

- You might find it strange at first, but you will **be** accustomed to
  it soon.
- You might find it strange at first, but you will **become**
  accustomed to it soon.

The second one seems to be correct! if I am right why is that?

Also, I am interested to know where we use **be**  and where we use **become** in general?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are both correct but emphasize different aspects of the accustomization.

The first emphasizes the final state: *you will **be** accustomed to it soon*.  I.e. at some point in the future (*soon*), you will find that you *are* used to it.

The second emphasizes the transition: *you will **become** accustomed to it soon*.  I.e., you will soon undergo the transformation from "not being used to it", to "being used to it."